# Flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 7.0 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, listtile, flutter-renderflex-error

I'm trying to fix this padding issue, but it still occur. And i want a gap below the buttons too. please help how to fix it.

Error:

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 7.0 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
```

Error is pointing on ListTile's `leading` and `trailing` Column.

[image]

Here is my code

```
    var appointmentCards = Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox100(),
        SizedBox20(),
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: category.length,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            // return upcomingAppointmentCard(context);
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 7),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 10,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "08:30",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontFamily: fontFamily),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Thurday",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontFamily: fontFamily),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "9 March 2021",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontFamily: fontFamily),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      trailing: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Dr. Maria",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontFamily: fontFamily),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Thurday",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontFamily: fontFamily),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "9 March 2021",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontFamily: fontFamily),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Row(
                    //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    //   children: [
                    //     Column(
                    //       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    //       children: const [
                    //         Text(
                    //           "08:30",
                    //           style: TextStyle(
                    //               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    //               color: Colors.black,
                    //               fontSize: 18,
                    //               fontFamily: fontFamily),
                    //         ),
                    //         Text(
                    //           "Thurday",
                    //           style: TextStyle(
                    //               color: Colors.black,
                    //               fontSize: 12,
                    //               fontFamily: fontFamily),
                    //         ),
                    //         Text(
                    //           "9 March 2021",
                    //           style: TextStyle(
                    //               color: Colors.black,
                    //               fontSize: 12,
                    //               fontFamily: fontFamily),
                    //         ),
                    //       ],
                    //     ),
                    //     SizedBox(
                    //       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                    //     ),
                    //     Column(
                    //       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    //       children: const [
                    //         Text(
                    //           "Dentist",
                    //           style: TextStyle(
                    //               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    //               color: Colors.black,
                    //               fontSize: 18,
                    //               fontFamily: fontFamily),
                    //         ),
                    //         Text(
                    //           "Dentist",
                    //           style: TextStyle(
                    //               color: Colors.black,
                    //               fontFamily: fontFamily),
                    //         ),
                    //         Text(
                    //           "Jinnah",
                    //           style: TextStyle(
                    //               color: Colors.black,
                    //               fontFamily: fontFamily),
                    //         ),
                    //       ],
                    //     ),
                    //     // SizedBoxWidth10(),
                    //   ],
                    // ),
                    SizedBox20(),
                    appointmentTile == 'Upcoming'
                        ? Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              customButtonWithWhiteBg(
                                  context,
                                  Text(
                                    "Cancel",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: fontFamily,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  ),
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                                  () {}),
                              customButtonWithWhiteBg(
                                  context,
                                  Text(
                                    "Reschedule",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: fontFamily,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  ),
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                                  () {}),
                            ],
                          )
                        : Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        SizedBox10(),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Can you attach `customButtonWithWhiteBg` code too?

Comment: Try using `padding` instead of `margin` for your `Container`

Comment: I found that setting `visualDensity` to your `ListTile` solves the problem, e.g. `visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: 4)`

Comment: please add simplified and  full code for better understanding

Comment: Problem is with `ListTile()`.

Comment: I think if you wrap your `column()` which is above `ListTile `with `Expanded` or `Flexible` than it might solve your issue, Try it once ,Please let me know if about it!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your Text Widgets inside [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) Widget.

```
    Card(
        elevation: 10,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "08:30",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "Thurday",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "9 March 2021",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              trailing: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "Dr. Maria",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "Thurday",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "9 March 2021",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("08:30",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 18)),
                                Text("Thurday ",
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12)),
                                Text("9 March 2021",
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12)),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Text("Dr. Maria",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 18)),
                                Text("Thurday",
                                    style:
                                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12)),
                                Text("9 March 2021",
                                    style:
                                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12)),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```